# Enable USB-Debugging and delete display pattern on OnePlus One Android 6

Tags: cyanogenmod, adb, recovery-mode, usb-debugging, oneplus-one

I tried to get some data from my OPO that i screen crashed 3 years ago. I'm not able to unlock it, because i forgot the display pattern. 
So the plan was to enable usb-debugging via adb in recovery and then to remove the pattern via adb command, but i guess it doesn't work with CM 13 Recovery. 
I put my new SIM into the OPO to get internet connection so that it can sign in into my google account automatically but it didn't, even though it was linked to this account when i used this phone.
Is there any possibility to unlock it? Or maybe to connect it as media device to my computer to get the data?

Back in the days i used to have TWRP Custom Recovery, it was pretty easy to connect with a computer and use the phone as a usb device while in recovery mode.

Comment: Is the bootloader unlocked? Also, not sure they work but years ago I did come across some links/software which claimed to  unlock OPO's bootloader without wiping data, so you may search and try them if all else fails.

Comment: to be honest, i'm not sure. i havent used it since 2017. when i reboot to bootloader a cm icon shows up and says "fast boot mode". I'm sorry for my bad knowledge, i really was good at this stuff years ago, but it's been 6 years or so since a flashed my last custom rom on my droid razr. so i'm really not into this stuff anymore :/

Comment: Setup [tag:fastboot] in your PC, reboot the device into fastboot mode and issue this command: `fastboot getvar all`. Among other things it should show you `(bootloader) unlocked:yes` or `no`. If yes, you can  flash or boot into TWRP easily.

Comment: thanks!!! I'll try when i come home. after i flashed twrp i can mount the opo as usb device in recovery, right?
is it also possible to activate usb debuggin in twrp? if not, its fine, but if yes it would be great.

Comment: USB Debugging and root access is enabled in twrp. You can alse enable MTP from there. Get whatever data you need from there.